# Timescaledb drop_chunks() call fails with function not found error when using JDBC driver

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

When I run the following code

```
dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);    
try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
  stmt.execute("SELECT drop_chunks(interval '24 hours', 'truck_message')");
  ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
  log.info("Executed drop_chunks() call. ResultSet: {}", rs);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
  log.warn("Failed to execute drop_chunks() call", ex);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
WARN [Thread Group 1-3] c.g.TruckMessageSampler: Failed to execute drop_chunks() call
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function drop_chunks(interval, unknown) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I can run this query through psql postgres client without problems but not through my Java application which is using a JDBC connection provided by HikariCP. I followed the hint in the log and tried several different ideas:

I have tried two other variant of the original query

```
"SELECT drop_chunks(interval '24 hours', 'truck_message'::name)"
```

and

```
"SELECT drop_chunks(older_than => interval '24 hours', schema_name=> 'vitm'::name, table_name => 'truck_message'::name)"
```

These all result in same error. The function is Timescaledb extension specific which is a postgres extension and is defined as follows:

```
someuser=# \df drop_chunks
List of functions
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Schema              | public
Name                | drop_chunks
Result data type    | SETOF regclass
Argument data types | older_than "any" DEFAULT NULL::unknown, table_name name DEFAULT NULL::name, schema_name name DEFAULT NULL::name, cascade boolean DEFAULT false, newer_than "any" DEFAULT NULL::unknown, "verbose" boolean DEFAULT false, cascade_to_materializations boolean DEFAULT NULL::boolean
Type                | func
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the missing piece of knowledge I needed was that functions are schema specific, so in my case I had to specify a schema. So the correct query was:

```
"SELECT public.drop_chunks(interval '24 hours', 'truck_message'::name)"
```

Comment: You should set the search_path so it contains public. Problem will be solved.