# TimescaleDB: delete rows to free space

Tags: timescaledb

I have still TimescaleDB 1.1.1 in use (upgrade is not possible now).
The table has about 100GB data and I deleted half of the rows already.
But there is no significant increase of free space on my disk.
I tried `VACUUM ANALYZE` too, but also no big deal.

How to drop chunks in order to free space in hypertables?

I tried:

```
SELECT drop_chunks('mydatatable', older_than => INTERVAL '9 months');
```

but got just:

```
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. 
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60124341/3286903) didn't help.

How to proceed?

Comment: I'd look in pg_catalog.pg_proc and make sure that the function exists and what data types it takes and then add explicit type casts and schema qualification as I don't remember what types the arguments took then. You might try first though using a cast to regclass for the table...

Comment: Did you try `VACUUM FULL`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html

Answer (score 0):

reindex the table with latest data

```
REINDEX TABLE mydatatable
```